# AndEngine ButtonSprite with single TextureRegion

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have a game that uses ButtonSprite as some of the UI element sprites.
For each button I have a Texture Region for Normal and Pressed States.

```java
mSomeBottonTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mLoadTextureAtlas, this, "SomeBotton.png", 0, 0);
mSomeBottonPressedTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mLoadTextureAtlas, this, "SomeBottonPressed.png", 0, 0);
ButtonSprite someButtonSprite = new ButtonSprite(0, 0, mSomeBottonTextureRegion, mSomeBottonPressedTextureRegion, mEngine().getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

I see there are no constructors that handle a ButtonSprite with a single TiledTextureRegion for which you can supply a different tile for each state.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to do this with ButtonSprite? Or will I have to Extend a TiledSprite and add button functionality so that I only have to make one TextureRegion instead of two.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just supply a TiledTextureRegion to the ButtonSprite as it is designed to handle 3 states - normal, pressed, and disabled. Check the ButtonSprite.java and you will see several alternate constructors that take a TiledTextureRegion and set the stateCount to the number of tiles in the TiledTextureRegion passed in.

Here's one of those constructors

```
public ButtonSprite(final float pX, final float pY, final ITiledTextureRegion pTiledTextureRegion, final VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager, final OnClickListener pOnClickListener) {
    super(pX, pY, pTiledTextureRegion, pVertexBufferObjectManager);

    this.mOnClickListener = pOnClickListener;
    this.mStateCount = pTiledTextureRegion.getTileCount();

    switch(this.mStateCount) {
        case 1:
            Debug.w("No " + ITextureRegion.class.getSimpleName() + " supplied for " + State.class.getSimpleName() + "." + State.PRESSED + ".");
        case 2:
            Debug.w("No " + ITextureRegion.class.getSimpleName() + " supplied for " + State.class.getSimpleName() + "." + State.DISABLED + ".");
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The supplied " + ITiledTextureRegion.class.getSimpleName() + " has an unexpected amount of states: '" + this.mStateCount + "'.");
    }

    this.changeState(State.NORMAL);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I seem to be blind.